# Redis on Heroku not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis

I'm trying to push some code to Heroku that requires a Redis server but I can't seem to get it working...I have a redis server running on my computer and the code is working perfectly fine in development but it's refusing to connect to the server on Heroku.

I have tried it with two different add-ons on Heroku (Redis To Go and Redis Cloud) with no luck.

In my initializers/redis.rb I have this:

```
uri = ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/"
Redis.current = Redis.new(:url => uri)
```

And I am sure that the `ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"]` that is showing in heroku config is exactly the same as the one that is on the heroku add on.

However when I push it to Heroku all I get is:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

Why is it still trying to connect to Redis on 6379? How can I force it to use the Heroku Redis but still be able to use it locally?

Thanks

Comment: Please humor me and lmk what your `REDIS_PROVIDER ` config var holds

Comment: Nice - now try looking into `REDIS_URL' and if it is populated, use that in your code. Lmk if this works so I can write it up as an answer:)

Comment: That doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I set `REDIS_URL` as the same value as`REDISTOGO_URL` and it helped me.

Also I have sidekiq configuration like that:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV.fetch("REDISTOGO_URL", "redis://localhost:6379") }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV.fetch("REDISTOGO_URL", "redis://localhost:6379") }
end
```